# dress in a uniform or dress uniform?

Tags: word-usage

> Employees who **dress in a uniform** every day might get bored.
>
> Employees who **dress a uniform** every day might get bored.

Which one is grammatical and which one is more idiomatic?

Comment: You can only dress yourself or another person; you can't _dress a uniform_ (put clothes on it). _Wear [a] uniform_ would be more idiomatic. (And a _dress uniform_, where _dress_ is an adjective, is a smart version of a military uniform worn on formal occasions.)

Comment: Why do you think the second option might be correct?

Comment: @Astralbee 
I just realised by reading your answer that there is a difference in meaning between dress and wear.  I thought "wear a uniform" is the same as "dress a uniform"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sentence is the only correct one.

"Uniform", when describing a set of standardised clothing, is a common noun and needs the indefinite article "a". You also need the preposition "in" to denote that the subject (the employees) is dressing *in* the uniform. To "dress a uniform" is certainly not idiomatic, but if it were to mean anything it would mean adding adornments to the uniform itself.

You could say that someone "*dresses uniformly*", but that is using an adverb form of the word "uniform" and does not necessarily refer to the kind of uniform worn by military, or certain workers etc.